# C# XNA SoundEffect.FromStream

Tags: c#, audio, xna, stream, soundeffect

I want to load on XNA SoundEffect.
I have tried to use:

```
SoundEffect.FromStream(TitleContainer.OpenStream(XXX));
```

The XXX is the addres but it require the address from the content and I want to search from the whole computer. Address like:

> C:\Users\PC\Desktop\programs

How do I do that?

Comment: I've found [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20772/loading-sound-in-xna-without-the-content-pipeline) searching on Google, maybe it could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
SoundEffect.FromStream(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open));
```

where path is the file path.

Comment: I have tried this.
I got a running error:
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Answer (score 0):

You should have your custom files in your content folder or debug folder so they gets distributed properly on release. I am not sure what happens if i load a file from a completely different path since there was no reason to do that.

If you really want to load from a path far down you could type "../" to go a map down, depends on where you put the solution how much maps you need to go down to reach the "c:\" but you can see in the debug information where it is looking for the file so that should not be a problem.

But i really advice you to use the proper locations for your custom content or you might end up changing tons when you want to release.